# hide/show tab bar/tab layout on scrolling in coordinator layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to hide/show the tab bar(not action bar) while scrolling up/down in a coordinator layout.
I have tried implementing the same technique used for action bar but it isn't fruitful

here is my xml code snippet

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/drawer_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background = "?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    />

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

It is working for the app bar but not for the tab bar.
how can this be achieved?
please advice?

edit: i just want the tab bar to scroll and not the app bar.

Answer (score 0):

The scroll flag used within the attribute app:layout_scrollFlags must be enabled for any scroll effects to take into effect. This flag must be enabled along with enterAlways, enterAlwaysCollapsed, exitUntilCollapsed, or snap.

You can use a combination of

> app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"

[Check out this guide.](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout)

Comment: works fine but i wish to scroll the tab bar only and not the appbar.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps set the height (and min-height) to: `?attr/actionBarSize`

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/drawer_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

Comment: still no change. tab bar either scrolls along with app bar or doesn't scroll at all.